# search query only return one user

Tags: laravel, eloquent

The code below is the method getting users but it only return one users.
For example, if I put `users?filter=michaele+jessy`, I want to get two users having michaele or jessy as first name and last name.

I am studying backend stuff. I can simply make json data from controlles like `users` or `users/{id}` but how do I make controllers and routes having `users/{id}/addresses`. I am researching on that but couldn't find any good examples.

Thank you.

```
public function getUsers($parameters){

        if (empty($parameters)) {
            return $this->filterUsers(User::all());
        }
        if (isset($parameters['filter'])) {
            $terms = explode(' ', $parameters['filter']);


            foreach ($terms as $term) {

                $users = User::where('first_name', 'like', '%' . $term . '%')->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $term . '%')->get();
            }
            return $this->filterUsers($users);
        }

        $whereclause = $this->getWhereClause($parameters);


        $users = User::where($whereclause)->get();
        return $this->filterUsers($users);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues here. Firstly, you're `explode()` is exploding by an empty space and not a `+`.

Changing this to explode by a `+` may solve the issue of correctly creating the `terms` array to search the `users` table correctly.

Secondy, you're foreach is always completing the query using `->get()`. You should only use `->get()` when completing the query. You should start your user query using:

```
$users = User::newQuery();
```

Then start your `foreach` and loop through each `$term` to query `->where()` or `->orWhere()` first_name/last_name.

Once it has looped through all `$terms`, outside of the foreach run:

```
$users = $users->get();
```

Comment: one thing is that I don't know the reason but when I get the parameters with "+" it's changed to empty space. That is why I used empty space as a delimiter. GREAT HELP I really appreciate what I have learned today!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to *thisisKelvins's* suggestion, I made the code more streamlined. 
Still I have got the problem returning only one result.
The code looks like this.

```
public  function getUsers($parameters)
    {


        if (empty($parameters)) {
            return $this->filterUsers(User::all());
        }
        if (isset($parameters['filter'])) {
            $terms = explode(' ', $parameters['filter']);

            foreach ($terms as $term) {

                $users = User::query()->where('first_name', 'like', '%' . $term . '%')->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
            }
            $users = $users->get();

            return $this->filterUsers($users);
        }

        $whereclause = $this->getWhereClause($parameters);
        $users = User::where($whereclause)->get();
        return $this->filterUsers($users);
    }
```